# Objc: Make a NSURL with a String that does not conform to RFC 2396

Tags: iphone, objective-c, formatting, nsstring, nsurl

I have this situation where I need to make a URL with a string that contains ".

For instance:

```
NSString *myStringWithURL = [NSString stringWithFormat: 
                             @"http://myurl.com/setParam.php?setName=
                             {\"name\":\"%@\"} ", name];
// myStringWithURL will return the desired URL but it is a String.
// of course I need it as URL in order to make the request.
NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL URLWithString : myStringWithURL]; 
                       //This will return nil.
```

So the question is how to get my URL to not return nil?

The part {"name":"My Name"} should be a JSON but this seemed simpler than using a NSDictionary and then using the parser of JSON and so on.

I thank you very much for your help!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding to convert your string

Comment: Hi Max, thank you for your answer. I used the following but it didn't work:[NSString stringWithFormat: 
                             @"http://myurl.com/setParam.php?setName=
                             {\"name\":\"%@\"} ", [name stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]; Maybe I'm doing it wrongly, did you mean making first the string name with the " already in place instead of Backslashing them directly?

Comment: can you post your URL string here?

Comment: [[NSString stringWithFormat: @"myurl.com/setParam.php?setName= {\"name\":\"%@\"} ", @"andreas" ] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]

Comment: so you have to wrap the whole URL and not only parameter